# How to print a variable that has a whitespace in its name in Jtwig/Twig?

Tags: twig, jtwig

Let's say I have a model in JSON:

```
{"Id": 123, "Full Name": "Foo Bar"}
```

I can output the value of *Id* in Jtwig like so: `{{ Id }}`

But how do I output the value of *Full Name*?

Comment: `{{ attribute(object, "Full Name") }}`

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It would be useful if I had a way to reference the model itself from the template as the *object*, however, I'm not able or unaware how to do it.

Comment: Don't know which framework you are using but something like `echo $twig->render('template.html', [ 'object' => json_decode($json), ]);`

Comment: @DarkBee Thanks. I'm actually using [Jtwig](http://jtwig.org), so it is limited in terms of features compared to twig. But I figured out my only option is indeed, as you suggested, to embedded the whole model in a variable that has a valid identifier name.

Answer (score 0):

So after reading the official docs and very few posts around the Internet that are vaguely related I've figured out there is no way to do it without the changes in the **Jtwig core**. The only solution would be to modify the input model for the template by embedding it in a variable that has a valid identifier name, for example:

```
{"data": {"Id": 123, "Full Name": "Foo Bar"}}
```

Then we can use `{{ data.Id }}` and `{{ data['Full Name'] }}` in the template.